# Comment lines in manifest of a jar

Tags: java, jar

Is there a way to insert a comment line in the manifest of a jar file?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can always use a keyword like X-JENS-COMMENT, and then put your comment in the value.

Use a wording which is certain not to collide with anything Sun could come up with :)

Comment: Nice idea. I do not really think that X-JENS-COMMENT will be a header name some Sun engineer will make up in the next few months :-)

Answer (score 16):

I am not sure whether it will work with a pure Java JAR manifest, but in a OSGi bundle manifest comments can be given like this.

```
Comment:This is comment
Manifest-Version:1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion:3
Bundle-Name:abc_X.X.X.X.jar
```

Comment: Good suggestion as any key can be added to a Manifest.

Answer (score 15):

The [manifest specification](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#JAR%20Manifest) does not describe any method for writing comments into the manifest, so I believe not.